# Matching function arguments using regex

Tags: regex

I have some obfuscated code which call functions, like this:

```
getAny([["text with symbols \"()[],.;\" and maybe 'ImVerySeriousFn'"], ...]);
setAny([["other text with \"()[],.;\""], ...]);...
```

Arguments contain random text. Functions follow each other without a new line.

How can I get arguments of `getAny`, `setAny` and other functions, using set of regular expressions?

I need this result:

```
regex1 result: [["text with symbols \"()[],.;\" and maybe 'ImVerySeriousFn'"], ...]
regex2 result: [["other text with \"()[],.;\""], ...]
...
```

I tried write `regex1`:

```
getAny\((.*)\)
```

but matching result also contains `setAny` call

```
 [["text with symbols \"()[],.;\" and maybe 'ImVerySeriousFn'"], ...]);setAny([["other text with \"()[],.;\""], ...]
```

When I tried:

```
getAny\((.*?)\)
```

matching result break argument string

```
[["text with symbols \"(
```

I can't split by `;` or `);` because text in arguments can contains symbols `;` or `);`

maybe impossible to do it using regex?

Comment: A parser is probably a better way to do this, but how about [this](http://regex101.com/r/oW2rL6/2)?: `[gs]etAny\((.*)\)`

Comment: Unfortunately,functions follow each other without a new line. `[gs]etAny\((.*)\)` - [it does not work](http://regex101.com/r/oW2rL6/3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex needs to be `\(.*?\);` since your code is obfuscated (and assumedly on one line).

Note that this will fail if one of your arguments contains `);` inside of it.

Explanation (From Regex101.com):

```
/\((.*?)\);/g
  \( matches the character ( literally
    1st Capturing group (.*?)
      .*? matches any character (except newline)
      Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed [lazy]
  \) matches the character ) literally
  ; matches the character ; literally
  g modifier: global. All matches (don't return on first match)
```

The main problem with your regex is that you never specified `;` to end a match, so it went ahead and grabbed up until the last `)` it saw because you used `.*`, which is greedy (grabs everything) unless followed by `?`.

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/cC7hM0/3)

Comment: You're assuming that the comma will be always there. I think the OP added the punctuation symbols to indicate that there could be "special" characters in between, and that shouldn't cause the regex to fail, and *not* as an argument delimiter.

Comment: @AmalMurali Fixed. Also, if you look at his input, commas are also being used as argument delimiters.

Comment: To rephrase: I think `(?:.+,)*?` is useless here since `.+` at the end is what is doing all the matching.

Comment: This regex just matches any text inside parentheses. Might as well write `\((.*)\)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer -- despite the commentary below, it doesn't offer enough explanation of what it does and why it solves the OP's problem. Can you explain it better please?

Comment: @EngineerDollery If you click the link that says "Demo", there's an explanation by regex101.com.

Comment: SO does not condone the use of links in place of content. The link will disappear and SO will be left with an incomplete or useless answer. The aim on SO is to create an archive of answers that are useful for the future, not just for the OP. Further, I personally, and many other SO users, will not follow links while in work, because we have no idea what lies on the other side of them.

Comment: @EngineerDollery You're the first person I've encountered that said anything like that.  Most SO users seem to encourage the use of links to clean up an answer by allowing them to omit the content that the link covers.  Also, have you not heard of hovering over a link to check where it goes?

Comment: Maybe, but you're not very experienced here, and people who tell you that are absolutely wrong. Your answer was flagged for review because it is considered low quality, and I'm one of the people reviewing it. Please check this out -- it'll help: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260411/reviewing-low-quality-posts-answers-without-explanation

Comment: @EngineerDollery Sorry for spamming your inbox with comments, but after reading over both of the links, I don't see how this doesn't meet the guidelines. According to the "How to Answer", I think I can solve this by adding some context for the link, such as "Here is a demo of the regex in action on Regex101.com", but I don't know if that will satisfy the requirements that I apparently missed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57562/discussion-between-engineer-dollery-and-revanprodigalknight).

Comment: +1 For the high-quality answer :) Thanks @RevanProdigalKnight

Comment: Text of arguments can contains also `);` Like this `getAny([["I'm 'getAny(..);'"], ...]);` [link](http://regex101.com/r/cC7hM0/5)

Comment: @sheh About the only other thing I can think of to do would be `\(\[(.*?)\]\);`, which will only fail if `]);` is found inside one of the arguments. It isn't really possible to make the regex any more robust than that, so far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if I understand your question, but if I do, you maybe could use a group and collect the allowed signs in it.

Your regex could be: `\( ( ) " [ ],\.; a-zA-Z \)`

outer brackets enclose the group

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your pattern correctly, your function argument will always start with `[["` and end with `"]]`.

Regex:

```
/getAny\((\[\[".*?[^\\]"\]\])\);/
```

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/jC3vX5/2

Note the lazy `.*?`, and `[^\\]` to make sure the matching quote is not escaped.